# Why does a select on an ordered DataFrame in Snowpark destroys ordering?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

In Snowpark (Python API, version 0.11.0), I try to order an Dataframe according to an attribute COUNT_OBJ, then show the top 5 EVENTDATES. I realized that the subsequent "select" destroys the ordering of the Dataframe. Is that to be expected? [image]

As a longterm spark developer, this is an unexpected behavior

**EDIT**: More output as requested in comments:

[image]

Comment: With a small table and unique values for COUNT_OBJ I am not able to reproduce (even setting USE_CACHED_RESULT=False). Do you have duplicate values for COUNT_OBJ? Can you maybe select COUNT_OBJ as well in second example and show the values?

Comment: @Sergiu there are some duplicates, but not in the top 5. It seems that the ordering is completely random (and non-determinisitc), re-running the query will produce other results. I updated the pictures above

Comment: I think it happens as explained [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SELECT-query-with-LIMIT-clause-returns-non-deterministic-result-if-ORDER-BY-clause-exists-in-different-level). The queries on the SELECT  (after the ORDER BY) include the LIMIT outside of the ORDER BY therefore producing non-deterministic results.

Comment: maybe related : https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/issues/646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Sergui in the comments, the problem ist the "limit" in the generated SQL (see https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SELECT-query-with-LIMIT-clause-returns-non-deterministic-result-if-ORDER-BY-clause-exists-in-different-level)

[image]

In my case, the solution is to swap the "limit" before the select like this:

In this case, the ordering remains

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is you are sorting the df but "show" will pull at random, not necessarily the first 5 entires.
If you want to order the entire dataframe and then get the first few entries you can use limit and cache_result()

```
df.sort(col("count_obj"), ascending=False).cache_result().limit(5).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by @Sergiu explains the issue. Both the order and limit clauses must be part of the same query. By storing the ordered result as a dataframe and then displaying a subset of the dataframe as an additional operation, you are separating these clauses.

The following works:
`df.order_by("COUNT_OBECT", ascending=False).select("EVENTDATE").show(5)`

You can also accomplish the same thing using SQL. Including `LIMIT 5` in the SQL string is necessary for retaining ordering.

```
query = """
SELECT EVENTDATE
FROM <table_name>
ORDER BY COUNT_OBECT DESC
LIMIT 5
""".strip()

df = session.sql(query)

df.show(5)
```